# Custom event/activity logging in Microsoft Access

Tags: database, ms-access

My goal is to design a portion of a database that captures the time an activity occurs or the time a record is updated. I would also like the database to set certain field values of new records in one table based on field values from the record of another table or query.

For the first goal, there will be 4 entities: *user*, *subject*, *activityLog* (intermediate entity for a many-to-many between *user* and *subject* with an updatedTime field in addition to the primary keys), and a *violation* entity. The *violation* entity will also have both users and subjects as foreign keys.

Each time a user adds a new subject record into the *violation* table or updates an existing record in the *violation* table, I would like the database to programmatically select the current record's values and copy those values into a new record (essentially duplicate the entire record or certain field values I choose) in the *activityLog* and set the current system date/time in its updatedTime field.

For the second goal, my agency has business rules that impose penalties for violations and the penalties are assessed based on first, second, third offenses. For example, if a subject commits 5 violations and 2 of the 5 are of the same violation type, then the penalty for the 2nd occurrence of the 2 violations that are the same should be elevated to a second offense penalty (all others will remain at 1st offense if no other violation types are 2 or more).

What I'd like the database to do is select the subjectID and violationID from the *activityLog* table, group by subjectID and count the number of violatonIDs. After typing this out, I am realizing that is basically a query. So, the results of this query will tell me how many times an individual committed a violation, and I'd write VBA code to update a table's record that contained the queried data (this table would be permanent...I have no clue what type of query this would be...update query, perhaps).

Based on the descriptions I have provided above, how would this design be rated as far as good/bad/efficient/inefficient? Please

Comment: First, saving calculated data is often unnecessary and risks data inconsistency. Do calculations in query or in textboxes when needed. If you want an audit trail of record edits, that is a fairly common topic in numerous forums. And for your penalty feature, write code. Your question is multi-part and too broad. There is no code for analysis. Answers would essentially be opinions. This is all not appropriate for SO and expect question will be closed. When you have code with specific issue, post question.

Comment: Overall approach sounds reasonable, although the separation of "activities" and "violations" – both with foreign keys to users and subjects – may not be necessary if they have a lot of common columns. In that case it might be better to store all activities in an "activity table" with a column having a flag or foreign key to designate the subset of all "activities" that are "violations".

Comment: You  would place your code in the forms before update event, and thus can write out data when data in a form is edited.